# Problema con lectura de matriz

Tags: c++

tengo un problema, tengo la siguiente funcion la cual es para generar un reporte sobre los valores minimos de cada columna de una matriz:

```
int min;
    cout<<"Numero   "<<"Fila   "<<"Columna   "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<tamc;i++)
    {
         min=m[0][i];
        for(int j=0;j<tamf;j++)
        {
            if(min>m[j][i])
            {
                 min=m[j][i];
                 cout<<"  "<<min<<"        "<<j<<"         "<<i;
                 cout<<endl;
            }

        }
    }
```

El problema es que el reporte debe de quedar como, por ejemplo si tengo la matriz:

2 4 1

3 1 5

9 7 2

El rerpote debe quedar como:

Numero | Fila | Columna

2        |       0    |        0

1        |       1       |      1

1         |      0        |     2

Pero el codigo que tengo en algunas ocasiones si saca bien el reporte pero a veces no muestra por todas las columnas o repite columnas y asi. y si intento poner el cout<<"  "<<min<<"        "<<j<<"         "<<i; y el cout<<endl; fuera del for secundario pero dentro del for de i, me imprime bien las columnas y numeros pero no se como hacer para que imprima las filas.

Alguien sabe que hice mal y como solucionarlo?

Comment: La verdad es que no tengo ni la mas minima idea que que hiciste mal. Con solo ver el codigo es complicado en la mayoria de los casos atinarle. Trata de publicar un [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Asi se nos hara mas facil ayudarte, ya que podremos probar el codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Imprimías los valores cada vez que se encontraba uno mas pequeño.

Así que, como tú dices, había que sacar ese cout del for secundario. Para ello tienes que declarar una variable en la que vas a guardar la línea donde se encuentra el mínimo, al igual que guardas el valor mínimo en la variable min.

El código quedaría como:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int tamf = 3, tamc = 3;
int m[tamf][tamc] = {
    {2,4,1},
    {3,1,5},
    {9,7,2}
};

int main(){
    cout <<"Numero   "<<"Fila   "<<"Columna   "<< endl;

    for(int i=0; i<tamc; i++){
        int min = m[0][i];
        int fila = i, col = 0;

        for(int j=0; j<tamf; j++){
            if(min > m[j][i]){
                min = m[j][i];
                col = j;
            }
        }
        cout   <<"  "<<min<<"        "<<col<<"         "<<fila<<   endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: me funciono, gracias!!!!